# console.log() locally uploaded csv file

Tags: javascript, filereader

This is a file upload handler I have in my code.

```
onFileUpload() {
    const file = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];

    const reader = new FileReader();    
    console.log('contents of file:', reader.readAsText(file));

    this.props.getFile(file); // an action
  }
```

This code snippet logs `undefined` to the console. What does it lack?

**UPDATE 1.**
The `render()` method in the React component. The `onFileUpload()` method was binded in the constructor with `this.onFileUpload = this.onFileUpload.bind(this)`.

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        ...
        <input type='file' id='files' className='file-input-hidden' onChange={this.onFileUpload} />
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: It is an asynchronous method. I see no event listeners added for when the Filereader is complete....

Comment: Look at the documentation example on MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/onload

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
onFileUpload() {
    const file = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];

    const reader = new FileReader()
    reader.onload = event => console.log(event.target.result)
    reader.onerror = error => throw(error)
    reader.readAsText(file)

    this.props.getFile(file); // an action
  }
```

You just have to add a listener to do the logging rather than doing it synchronously

Comment: As it stands now `reject(error)` would return an error `reject is undefined`.

Comment: @ElAnonimo updated with throw. Pardon the mistake

Comment: I deleted the comment you responded to cause the issue was with me having two `reader.onload()` calls in `onFileUpload()`. I had it like this: https://pastebin.com/XfF1m764